# How to get dropdownlist selected value on controller action

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have created a model using a `List` and a `DistrictId`
Here is my Model:

```
public class ObjectModel
{
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select District")]
    [Display(Name = "Select District")]
    public IList<SelectListItem> DistrictNamesModel { get; set; }
    public int DistrictId { get; set; }
  }
```

Here is my view:
By this view i am creating a drown list and populating it with District Values and Text

```
@model MVCtrendsetters.Models.ObjectModel
....

@using (Html.BeginForm("Insert", "AppForm", FormMethod.Post,                                         new { @enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    ....
    @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DistrictNamesModel, Model.DistrictNamesModel , "--Select--", new { @id = "ddlDistrict"});
    <input type="submit" value="Create" />
}
```

Here is my Controller:
I used Stored procedures for database and DB is a database connection and query class.

```
ObjectModel OM = new ObjectModel();
DB dd = new DB();
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds = dd.getAllDistrict();
List<SelectListItem> DistrictNames = new List<SelectListItem>();
foreach (DataRow item in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
{
    DistrictNames.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = item["CityName"].ToString(), Value = (item["Id"].ToString()) });
}
OM.DistrictNamesModel = DistrictNames;
return View(OM);

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Insert(ObjectModel OM , string DistrictId)
{
    return View(OM);
}
```

My question is how will i get `DistrictId` in `[Httpost]` Insert           method. I used a drop-down which is filled correctly.  My table has Column Name City and Id.

Comment: Your DDL declaration needs to be: `@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.DistrictId, Model.DistrictNamesModel , "--Select--", new { @id = "ddlDistrict"});` <- the first argument is the property the selected item's value is bound to

Comment: And you do not need the 2nd parameter `string DistrictId` in your method (`ObjectModel` already contains a property `DistrictId`)

Comment: Thank you Geoff and Stephen....I am new to MVC so did some silly mistakes ...

Comment: but my Model.State is returning false :(

Comment: You need to remove `[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please Select District")]` from `IList<SelectListItem> DistrictNamesModel` and add it to `int DistrictId`

Comment: may i know the reason? why? thanks

Comment: Because your binding to `DistrictId`, not `DistrictNamesModel`. And you don't (and should not) create form controls for each property of each `SelectListItem` so `DistrictNamesModel` is `null` when you POST (as it should be) but because you have `[Required]` it means `ModelState` is invalid.